# used directory Test-Path vs System.IO.File in powershell

Tags: powershell

Tying to install SQL server on K drive and if no K drive than install on P drive. I have try follow but not working. power-shell always install on P drive. Any info will help.

$SQLInstanceDir = "K:\MSSQL"

```
    if( ! (Test-Path $SQLInstanceDir) ){ 
                      $SQLInstanceDir = "P:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
```

and`enter code here`
 $SQLInstanceDir = "K:\MSSQL"

```
         if(![System.IO.File]::Exists($SQLInstanceDir)){
                          $SQLInstanceDir = "P:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
```

Comment: after i add the missing final `}` and change the 1st location to one that exists on my system ... it works as expected. //// so ... does `K:\MSSQL` exist on that system AND does the account have permission to see that location?

Comment: This is what I have     $SQLInstanceDir = "K:\MSSQL"
            # if K:\MSSQL does not exist...
            if( ! (Test-Path $SQLInstanceDir)){ 
                              $SQLInstanceDir = "P:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
            }

Comment: so ... my question was "does that path exist when that script is run AND for the account that is running that script"? if you use the account in question, and run ONLY the `Test-Path -Path "K:\MSSQL`, does that return true? ///// also, have you tried typing in the path manually? it may be that you are copying a hidden character in the `"K:\MSSQL"` value ...

Comment: How about something as simple as `$SQLInstanceDir=If('K' -in (Get-PSDrive).Name){'K:\MSSQL'}else{'P:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server'}`, so you are really just testing against the drive, not a specific path.

Comment: TheMadTechnician - not working . it only looking K Drive  and do not  look for else{'P:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server'}